# Cannot uninstall BitDefender

Tags: 12.04, uninstall

I installed Bitdefender on my Ubuntu 12.04 machine a little while ago, but have since realised that the ppa no longer has a folder to support the precise distro, thus I cannot update the BitDefender software and I am getting all sorts of error messages.

I have decided to uninstall BitDefender, but my problem is that when I run the standard command line commands to uninstall*, I am told that the BitDefender package cannot be found. I have done a root folder search for BitDefender, and the packages are definitely there, I just can't do anything with them. Is there any solution to this?

*The commands I have tried are:

```
sudo apt-get remove BitDefender-Scanner
sudo apt-get purge BitDefender-Scanner
sudo apt-get purge BitDefender-Scanner-GUI
sudo apt-get purge BitDefender-Scaner BitDefender-Scanner-GUI
```

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using synaptic to remove bit defender.
You can find synaptic in ubuntu software center.

Comment: That worked. Thanks a million. I'm shocked I didn't think of that myself, but I've never had a need to much use Synaptic before now (At least not since my 8.04 system). Its a bit early in the morning for this anyway...